# Derivative of $x\cdot|x|$ on $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

$$f(x) = x |x|$$

[Wolfram Alpha says is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate%20x*abs%28x%29&dataset=):

$$f'(x) = \frac{2x^2}{|x|}$$

and thus $f'(0)$ is indeterminate, while an HP48 says that:

$$f'(x) = |x| + x \operatorname{sgn} x,$$

which would yield $f'(0) = 0$. If I say that:

$$f(x) = -x^2$$

for $x<0$, 0 for $x=0$ and:

$$f(x) = x^2$$

for $x>0$, I kinda think that $f'(0)$ is 0; all three parts' derivatives converge to $0$ on $x=0$, and thus I think that Wolfram is wrong, but I don't really dare say that! (but I don't see any spiky bits on $f(x)$, although it seems clear to me that $f''(0)$ is indeterminate).

(excuse my poor TeX)

edit: according to the answer below, it seems that Wolfram Alpha is wrong- I've already sent them some feedback, but can anyone elaborate on that?

Comment: Actually $f'(x)=2x^2/|x|$ has a limit for $x\to0$ because the limits $x\to0^+$ and $x\to0^-$ are the same.You actually can write that $f'(x)=2|x|$.

Comment: When you write x \text{sgn} x, you see $x \text{sgn} x$, but when you write x \operatorname{sgn} x, you see $x \operatorname{sgn} x$, with proper spacing on the left and right.  With x\operatorname{sgn} (x) you see $x\operatorname{sgn} (x)$ with space to the left and not to the right.  In other words, the appropriate typesetting conventions for \operatorname{} and for \text{} are built in to the software and are different from each other. I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Tom-Tom but the existence of the limit does not make the "hole" at $x=0$ disappear, right?

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks! It's been +10 years since I've touched TeX and I never was good at it. I couldn't remember how to write log-likes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For $f'(0)$, let's not worry about values of $f'(x)$ *near* $0$. Let us instead compute directly from the definition of derivative. By definition,
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h|h|-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}|h|=0.$$

Comment: Cool, thanks! But then, is Wolfram Alpha really wrong?

Comment: You are welcome. Alpha is being less precise than it might (should) be.  Certainly less precise than you are. However, one can take the point of view that a removable singularity is not quite a singularity.  I am puzzled at the HP48, did you quote their $f'(x)$ correctly?

Comment: Oh, I copied it wrong, it is fixed now.

Comment: Good, it is a relief that it did not give a wrong answer. My first calculator was an HP!

Answer (score -1):

Note that,
  $|x| =  \sqrt{x^2}$.

Now,  use the derivation rules (chain and product) and you will see that $ f'(x) = |x| +  \dfrac{x^2}{|x|} =  \dfrac{2|x|^2}{|x|} = 2|x|$.

Thus, the wolfram is not wrong. We realize that we suppose x nonzero.

Comment: The thing is, my question is about precisely $x=0$...